# Install Ruby on Rails using rvm on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails using rvm on ubuntu 12.04. I am following the steps given in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm , but I am unable to install Rails successfully. When I run `gem install rails`, it does nothing.
Previously, by using the above link, I have successfully installed it several times. But this time, i couldn't.

Output of
`gem install rails -V`:

```
HEAD https //rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz 302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https //s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz 
200 OK 
GET https //rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz 
302 Moved Temporarily ... 
GET https //rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rack-1.4.5.gemspec.rz 
302 Moved Temporarily
```

It always stops at this point. Need some guidance to successfully install it.

Comment: The problem was with the network, I was using for installation. It used to connect and disconnect with [rubygems server](http://rubygems.org/). So while installing, when it used to disconnect, it hung up. I downloaded the rails gem and all its dependent gem and then installed it successfully.

Comment: Hey Here is a very fine installation ,...step by step...
http://solveubuntu.blogspot.in/p/in.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step One** — Install Ruby with RVM

Before we do anything else, we should run a quick update to make sure that all of the packages we download to our VPS are up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once that's done, we can start installin
g RVM, Ruby Version Manager. This is a great program that lets you use several versions of Ruby on one server; however, in this case, we will just use it to install the latest version of Ruby on the droplet.

If you do not have curl on your system, you can start by installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

To install RVM, open terminal and type in this command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

After it is done installing, load RVM. You may first need to exit out of your shell session and start up a new one.

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

In order to work, RVM has some of its own dependancies that need to be installed. To automatically install them:

rvm requirements
You may need to enter your root password to allow the installation of these dependencies.

On occasion the zlib package may be reported as missing. The RVM page describes the issue and the solution in greater detail here.

**Step Two** — Install Ruby

Once you are using RVM, installing Ruby is easy.

```
rvm install ruby
```

The latest ruby is now installed. However, since we accessed it through a program that has a variety of Ruby versions, we need to tell the system to use the version we just installed by default.

```
rvm use ruby --default
```

**Step Three** — Install RubyGems

The next step makes sure that we have all the required components of Ruby on Rails. We can continue to use RVM to install gems; type this line into terminal.

```
rvm rubygems current
```

**Step Four** — Install Rails
Once everything is set up, it is time to install Rails. To start, open terminal and type in:

```
gem install rails
```

This process may take a while, be patient with it. Once it finishes you will have Ruby on Rails installed on your droplet.

Answer (score 1):

i did this:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
sudo apt-get install git-core
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reload
rvm requirements
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion
rvm install ruby-2.0
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: @Bijendra: because i will need git to make my gemfile point to some specific gem sources. Additionally my version control is git.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Installing rvm wih stable ruby](https://rvm.io/rvm/install), use this command

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

After successful installation of ruby, install rails as a gem.

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic Vagrant box you can find to get Rails on Ubuntu. (This uses Ubuntu 14, but you can just change the box, should work roughly the same).

https://github.com/joelgerard/rails-vagrant

Also, checkout the [bootstrap.sh](https://github.com/joelgerard/rails-vagrant/blob/master/bootstrap.sh) if you want straight forward BASH.