# How to Run different Ruby versions and Rails version on same development machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a development machine running `ruby 1.9.3p545` and rails version `Rails 3.2.13` and currently has 5 applications with their capistrano scripts.

I now want to develop a new application using the same machine but with `Ruby 2.0.0` and `Rails 4.1`.

How can i do this without conflict. Thanx!

Comment: [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

Comment: Use either rvm or rbenv.

Comment: use rvm which manages the ruby version, you can install different different ruby versions by using rvm, you can search on net about the installation of rvm, for Ubuntu OS you can follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300791/install-ruby-on-rails-using-rvm-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) is another option, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153521/what-are-the-differences-between-rbenv-rvm-and-chruby

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Rbenv: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Ruby-build: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build

**Rbenv Installation**

As root

```
cd /opt
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git rbenv

touch /etc/profile.d/rbenv
echo 'export RBENV_ROOT=/opt/rbenv' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv
echo 'export PATH=/opt/rbenv/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv
```

edit **/root/.bashrc** and add on the very top of the file

```
source /etc/profile.d/rbenv
```

edit **/home/#your_user_name#/.bashrc** and add on the very top of the file

```
source /etc/profile.d/rbenv
```

**Ruby-build installation**

```
exec $SHELL
mkdir -p $RBENV_ROOT/plugins
cd $RBENV_ROOT/plugins
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
echo 'export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> /etc/profile.d/rbenv
exec $SHELL
```

At that point you are all set-up, ready to install any version of ruby

**Ruby Installation**

Example with versions 2.1.2 and 1.9.3p545, but you can choose any version you want

```
rbenv install 2.1.2
rbenv install 1.9.3p545
```

**Set global version of ruby**

```
rbenv global 2.1.2
```

**Set locale version of ruby**

```
cd /your/project/directory
rbenv local 1.9.3p545
```

**Install Bundler**

Note that before running bundler from your application root to install your gems you will have to install bundler it self with the following command

```
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri bundler rake
rbenv rehash
```

**Update rbenv**

```
cd /opt/rbenv
git pull
cd /opt/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git pull
rbenv rehash
```

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout this awesome article: [Phusion Passenger & running multiple Ruby versions](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/)

Basically, you could use rvm and reverse proxy to get it done. In your case, ruby -v 2.0.0, if you use passenger you could:

- rvm use 2.0.0
- gem install passenger --pre
- cd /path/to/your/app
- passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d
- setup reverse proxy in your apache config

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.hamburgers.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/app/public
    PassengerEnabled off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

you could also try use unicorn instead of passenger, or replace apache with ngix.